# Python re find diferent words with same pattern

Tags: python, regex, find, python-re

I'm having a problem with this activity, I want search the words s/ABS, c/ABS, s/servo, c/servo, s/ESP, c/ESP, s/válvula, c/válvula and it would be great if it also matches s/c+ all of the previous words.

Here, there is an example that I have used to make my tries:

```py
a = "12222/133-164 s/ABS s/abs s/A s/a puerta s/ESP s/servo s/a 4/5,hola s/s / r,147 / Spazio / Vivace, Tiida 1.8 - Visia/Acenta s/B, c/válvula"

regex = re.compile( r" /+ABS\b|servo\b|ESP\b|válvula\b ", flags=re.I | re.X)

print(regex.findall(a))
```

But my output is

```
['/ABS', '/abs', 'ESP', 'servo', 'válvula']
```

It has to be:

```
['s/ABS', 's/abs', 's/ESP', 's/servo', 'c/válvula']
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all "s/c+ all of the previous words" you can either use a character class `[sc]` (but that can also match `c/ABS`

```
\b[sc]/(?:ABS|servo|ESP|válvula)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIqn3j/1)

Or more precise:

```
\b(?:s/(?:ABS|servo|ESP)|c/válvula)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ca3tge/1)

```
import re

a = "12222/133-164 s/ABS s/abs s/A s/a puerta s/ESP s/servo s/a 4/5,hola s/s / r,147 / Spazio / Vivace, Tiida 1.8 - Visia/Acenta s/B, c/válvula"
regex = re.compile(r"\b(?:s/(?:ABS|servo|ESP)|c/válvula)\b", flags=re.I)

print(regex.findall(a))
```

Output

```
['s/ABS', 's/abs', 's/ESP', 's/servo', 'c/válvula']
```